# How to reinstall brew on El Capitan?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I'm stuck to reinstall brew, ruby on El Capitan.

Actually I didn't remember how exactly it occurs, but I lost my brew and I don't get reinstall it.

This is the message I receive when I try to reinstall it:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

First, some information:

```
>which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

>ruby --version
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin12.6.0]
```

And, if I try to fix ruby:

```
>rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-head] # security released on head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551]
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p643]
[ruby-]2.1.4
[ruby-]2.1[.5]
[ruby-]2.2[.1]
[ruby-]2.2-head
ruby-head

>rvm install 2.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
About to install Homebrew, press `Enter` for default installation in `/usr/local`,
type new path if you wish custom Homebrew installation (the path needs to be writable for user)
: 
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

How to proceed now?

Comment: Could you do a `which ruby` and `ruby --version` I want to see what ruby are you using?

Comment: which ruby  
/usr/local/bin/ruby  
ruby --version  
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin12.6.0]

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md)?

Comment: Uninstall brew first using `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"` and install it again using `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`.

Comment: @mattexx, Yes I looked it. Thanks

Comment: @zulhfreelancer, I got the same error: <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)  from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem.

I ran `type -a ruby` and saw I had installed two ruby: one on /usr/bin and another on /usr/local/bin

I just `mv /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rubybkp` and solve the problem

After this I ran `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` to reinstall brew.

Comment: I ran that curl command and was prompted to uninstall my existing brew first: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above, just note that installing brew now uses Bash:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Warning: The Ruby Homebrew installer is now deprecated and has been rewritten in Bash. 
Please migrate to the following command:
      /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```